# Join with junction table, how to?

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a schema, that looks so:

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_users` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `available` varchar(1) NOT NULL

) DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sys_groups_list` (

  `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

) DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sys_groups_junction` (

 `group_id` INT NOT NULL, /* <-- Refers to sys_groups_list.id */
 `usr_id` INT NOT NULL /* <-- Refers to sys_users.id */

) DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

On input, I have an `id` of some user.
On output, the result must look like so:

```
id  | last_name | available | group_name
... | ........  | ......... | ..........
```

I'm not sure how to write 3 `JOIN`s correctly to accomplish this, anytime I try I end up with syntax errors. So can you suggest how to write the SQL correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sys_users.id, lastname, available, sys_groups_list.name
FROM sys_users
JOIN sys_groups_junction
ON sys_users.id = sys_groups_junction.usr_id
JOIN sys_groups_list
ON sys_groups_junction.group_id = sys_groups_list.id
```